# Recover hard disk from Raw format

Tags: ssd, dd

I have been all over the web today with no results.

So my drive was encrypted (truecrypt) the whole drive where windows resided.
I decided to partition it to install W8 and forgot it was encrypted.
So the drive got damaged and not accessible. When connected to a computer
it asks for formatting. Somehow I enabled the drive through TrueCrypt on another computer
and I could see and get all the files.
Then I decided to decrypt the drive thinking that everything would be back to normal.
After decryption my drive is not NTFS it is in RAW format. I am trying every possible way to recover, and I am desperate enough to ask lol.

I tried:
ddrescue (linux) (not mountable, no signature, ntfsfix no good) 
testdisk (linux and windows) Sees the partitions but cant do anything 
Many recovery applications. etc etc.

I read in different places that doing a quickformat to NTFS and then doing a data recovery might help. I would definitely like a second opinion. 
Any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Hi There. This question isn't programming related and is off-topic here.

Comment: First of all, If you can, before you start using any program to recover, copy whole raw disk with dd or ddrescue. Just do something like `dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/backup/backup.image`